# Block size and text centering

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I tried to arrange three buttons in a block.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.3/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 text-center place-content-center">
   <div class="bg-blue-100 hover:bg-blue-400 h-images ">
       <a class=" "
           href="#">Button 1</a>
   </div>
   <div class="">
       <a href="#">Button 2</a>
   </div>
   <div class="">
       <a href="#">button 3</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

The picture was set to the size in the file tailwind.config.js, It turned out to be 810px, how can I make the buttons the size of this picture, and the text in the center of the block?
Tried setting automatic height `h-100`, `h-full`but it doesn't work.
Only the h-screen works, but then the buttons become the size of the screen, and not the block in which they are located.
[image: How should it look]

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Could you please add a snapshot of what is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.3/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 text-center place-content-center" style="align-items:center;">
   <button class="bg-blue-100 hover:bg-blue-400 h-images " style="min-width:auto; margin: auto; min-height:810px;">
       <a class=" "
           href="#">Button 1</a>
   </button>
   <div class="">
       <a href="#">Button 2</a>
   </div>
   <div class="">
       <a href="#">button 3</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

If you don't mind an inline CSS then you can try this code to set the height of your button to 810px, which as you said the size(height) of the image that you have. The width was set to auto for it to adjust with your image size.

Answer (score 0):

It bit a little unclear. I think this is what all you need

```css
.d-block{
    display: block;
}
.button{
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.button:hover{
  backround-color:#d7eeff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.3/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-block">
   <div class="bg-blue-100 hover:bg-blue-400 h-images button">
       <a class=""
           href="#">Button 1</a>
   </div>
   <div class="button hover:bg-blue-400">
       <a class="" href="#">Button 2</a>
   </div>
   <div class="button hover:bg-blue-400">
       <a class="" href="#">button 3</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "**display: inline**" to make buttons align horizontally, or "**display:inline-flex**" to also include same width to all buttons according to width of the screen.

//CSS

```
.btn-style{min-width:auto; margin: auto; min-height:210px;width:32.9%;}
```

//HTML

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 text-center place-content-center" style="display:inline; align-items:center;">
   <button class="bg-blue-100 hover:bg-blue-400 h-images btn-style">
       <a class=""
           href="#">Button 1</a>
   </button>
   <button class="bg-blue-100 hover:bg-blue-400 h-images btn-style">
       <a href="#">Button 2</a>
   </button>
   <button class="bg-blue-100 hover:bg-blue-400 h-images btn-style">
       <a href="#">button 3</a>
   </button>
</div>
```